# Laravel merge Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have 2 tables `bookings` and `eventDates`.

`bookings` table has 2 fields `checkIndate` and `checkOutDate` which points to `eventDates` table.

I setup following relationships

```
public function eventCheckInDate() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'EventDate', 'checkInDate' );
}
public function eventCheckOutDate() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'EventDate', 'checkOutDate' );
}
```

How can I combine those relationship so that eloquent only runs single query and get the data?

What happens now is it run 2 queries even if `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate` are still the same.

Thank you

Comment: but why you are creating two methods for the same record I mean didn't it get the same row? what if we remove one method?

Comment: @MahendraPratap because `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate` could be same or different for a booking.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need something like that. create another method for merging two relations.

```
public function getEventsInOutDateAttribute($value)
{
    $eventCheckInDate = $this->eventCheckInDate;
    $eventCheckOutDate = $this->eventCheckOutDate;

    // Merge collections and return single collection.
    return $eventCheckInDate->merge($eventCheckOutDate);
}
```

Comment: that is for attribute not for relationship so if I am displaying 10 rows on the same page this will still run duplicate queries.

Comment: you can use load() to run any relationship you want, load run after the query if any matches found. like Bookings::load('eventCheckInDate')->get();, only Bookings::all(); won't run relationship.

Comment: this throws me `Undefined method: merge()` error. `eventCheckInDate` returns `belongsTo` relation. I think that is the reason.